# Stretch container div around large nested elements

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site which displays a very large data set to the user which they can scroll across horizontally.  I'm having some trouble with the behaviour of div widths when implementing this.

Essentially I need an outer div with a horizontal scroll and all the data displayed inside this.  I have the following simple code to do this:

```
<div id="outer" style="height:100px;overflow:auto">
    <div id="inner" style="border: 1px solid green;padding:3px;">
        <div id="details" style="background-color:red;width: 300%">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the border defined on the "inner" div does not expand around the "details" div giving the result seen in this image: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/1719/capturepw.png

Any simple solution to this with HTML and CSS?

**Update:** The "width: 300%" on details is simply to simulate the large dataset.  There is no way of knowing how wide this dataset will be beforehand.

Comment: This isn't at you personally Jason, but think about it: you've just tagged your question using the normal tags system. Why put them in the title too? I've edited them out.

Comment: What kinda of data will you be displaying? Could you post an image of how you hope it will look?

Comment: It's a large table of data.  Unfortunately I can't get an image until at least Monday now

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width` on `inner` for `100%`, `300px`, basically anything but a percentage over 100. Going with 300% will make the element 3 times the width of its parent, but won't influence it.

**Edit:**

Putting a `300%` width won't yield the same reaction from your layout as containing lots of dummy content. Try putting some [dummy content](http://www.lipsum.com/) in the `details` element and remove the `width`. You'll have a more realistic result.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `width` off the `details div` and add it the `inner div`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/n88tT/

Comment: The width on details is simply to simulate the large data set.  On the real site there's no way of knowing the size of this beforehand.  I'll update the question to state this